# PyCrypto Not Printing Properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, pycrypto

Hi so before I was getting the IV in front (decrypted value of IV I believe it was) of the decrypted string.  Now I don't get the string...  How do I make this work, been trying for hours now...

My code:

```
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    import hashlib
    import base64
    import os
    import string

    iv = os.urandom(16)
    key = hashlib.sha256(b'mypassword123').digest()
    plaintext = (b'the password is totally not secure')
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    ciphertext = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
    print (ciphertext)
    print ("IV = ",iv)
    ciphertext = ciphertext.split(iv)
    ciphertext = str(ciphertext)[1].strip()
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    print (plaintext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encrypt` will change `cipher`, you have to make a new one;
and `str` will change `byte` to `repr(byte)`, like below:

```
a=b'xxx'
str(a) # "b'xxx'"

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
import base64
import os
import string

iv = os.urandom(16)
key = hashlib.sha256(b'mypassword123').digest()
plaintext = (b'the password is totally not secure')
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
ciphertext = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
print (ciphertext)
print ("IV = ",iv)
ciphertext = ciphertext.split(iv)
ciphertext = ciphertext[1]
cipher2 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
plaintext = cipher2.decrypt(ciphertext)
print (plaintext)
```

detail see [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)